# Passing a value from one Task Sequence Variable to another during OSD

Tags: imaging, sccm-2012

We are playing around with Task Sequence variables in SCCM 2012 Sp1. We are reimaging Operating systems wirelessly and one of the problems we've run into is that when assigning the computer name the computer cannot connect to AD to query the %computername% variable so it assigns it a random Mini-xxxx name.
One way we have thought about doing this is by storing the initial OSDComputerName and passing it back to the computer further down the OSD Task sequence. The initial value is stored correctly but when we try and pass that value into OSDComputerName we are getting the name of the variable and not the contents. How do we pass the contents of one Variable into another?

If anyone knows of a better way to do this then that would be great. I considered giving the computer a generic name and then renaming it when AD can be queried but was unsure how to even start approaching that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just by setting OSDComputerName using the Set Task Sequence Variable step, as long as it's set before the Setup Windows and ConfigMgr step it will use the value of that variable at that step.

Answer (score 1):

As @MartynCoup mentioned below, you can assign the OSDComputerName under the collection, this will prompt the user to enter a computer name just before deployment begins. Further info - http://www.windows-noob.com/forums/index.php?/topic/5542-how-can-i-easily-prompt-for-a-computer-name-in-configuration-manager-2012/

A slightly more dynamic approach - http://itx-solutions.nl/2012/11/sccm-osd-dynamic-computer-naming-dynamically-generate-computer-name/